# Crystal Report in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

In visual studio 2008 I cannot find crystal report option in the Templates pane of Add New Item dialog box. Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your programs whther u have got installed with crystal report basic for visualstudio 2008.

Note:not Runtime only basic

If not reinstall your visual studio 2008 professional.